# most likely I am allocating memory incorrectly somewhere

Tags: c, function, memory

please help me. I have a function. it should delete the row under the index number. I'm creating a new two-dimensional array. I allocate memory for it. I clear the memory from the source array and allocate it for it again.

```
int **matrix;
```

it is my matrix

```
int** delete_with_index(int n,int m, int **arr, int index){
    int i, g;
    int **new_arr;
    new_arr= malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        new_arr[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (g=0;g<m;g++){
            new_arr[i][g]=arr[i][g];
        }
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    arr= malloc((n-1)*sizeof(int *));
    for (i=0;i<(n-1);i++){
        arr[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i=0;i<index;i++){
        for (g=0;g<m;g++){
            arr[i][g]=new_arr[i][g];
        }
        free(new_arr[i]);
    }
    for (i=index+1;i<n;i++){
        for (g=0;g<m;g++){
            arr[i][g]=new_arr[i-1][g];
        }
        free(new_arr[i-1]);
    }
    free(new_arr);
    return arr;
}
```

it is my func

```
res_m = delete_with_index(n1, m1, res_m, index);
```

it is how i call it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have not asked a question nor described a specific error/problem. Please give a complete [mre] as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: when i call it my program crush with Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70489598/edit) the question to update it with all requested info. Not in comments.

Comment: I am creating exactly the same matrix as the original one. then I clean the original one. I allocate such an amount for it so that it becomes not n*m, but (n-1)* m, because I need to delete one line

Comment: Again, please provide a complete [mre]. We need exact code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The last `for` loop is wrong. `arr[i][g]=new_arr[i-1][g];` should be `arr[i-1][g]=new_arr[i][g];`

Comment: exactly! big thanks!

Comment: BTW, there is no need for `new_arr` at all. That's a waste of cpu cycles to make a copy of `arr`. Just use the original `arr`.

Comment: and how? i dont understand

Comment: Remove the `new_arr` allocation and copy. Allocate a new array called `arr1` with size (n-1)*m. Copy from `arr` to `arr1.` free `arr`. Return `arr1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not 2D array only array of pointers. You do not have to copy all the elements, only the pointers. You do not have to pass size of allocated memory for every row as it is not needed.
2. Use correct types for sizes
3. You do not need a new array but this function will allocate and return one if `createnew` parameter is `true`.

```
int **deleteROW(const size_t rows, int **arr, size_t index, int createnew, int freeDeleted)
{
    int **newArray = NULL;

    if(arr && rows)
    {
        if(createnew)
        {
            newArray = malloc(sizeof(*newArray) * (rows - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            newArray = arr;
        }
        if(newArray)
        {
             if(freeDeleted) free(arr[index];
             memmove(newArray, arr, index * sizeof(*newArray));
             memmove(newArray + index, arr + index + 1, (rows - index - 1) * sizeof(newArray));
        }  
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

If you simply want to delete a row from the array of pointers:

```
int **deleteROW(const size_t rows, int **arr, size_t index, int freeDeleted)
{
    int **newArray = NULL;

    if(arr && rows)
    {
        if(freeDeleted) free(arr[index])
        memmove(&arr[index], &arr[index + 1], (rows - index - 1) * sizeof(*newArray));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

If you want to delete a row from a real 2D array you simply need to:

```
void *deleteROW(const size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*arr)[cols], size_t index)
{
    if(arr && rows && cols && index < rows - 1)
    {
        memmove(arr[index], arr[index + 1], (rows - index - 1) * sizeof(*arr));
    }
    return arr;
}
```